# "Class web does not exist" Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, class, laravel, frameworks

Recently I've been working on a website using the Laravel PHP Framework, and on my local machine I've been using Laravel 5.2; however, how that I want to switch to a host to host my site (GoDaddy) they only support Laravel 5.1, and when I upload my code I get an error page saying "Class web does not exist".

Any help?

Comment: which plan are you using on GoDaddy? That is strange, a server provider can't limit you on technology version. I was able to host my website on GoDaddy's economy plan where they don't even let you install your own packages